# Singleton variable in branch

Tags: prolog

I was solving the second part of the second day of Advent of code problem with Prolog. They ask me to do some kind of validation, with the following verbiage:

> Each policy actually describes two positions in the password, where 1
> means the first character, 2 means the second character, and so on.
> (Be careful; Toboggan Corporate Policies have no concept of "index
> zero"!) Exactly one of these positions must contain the given letter.
> Other occurrences of the letter are irrelevant for the purposes of
> policy enforcement.
>
> Given the same example list from above:
>
> - `1-3 a: abcde` is valid: position 1 contains `a` and position 3 does not.
> - `1-3 b: cdefg` is invalid: neither position 1 nor position 3 contains `b`.
> - `2-9 c: ccccccccc` is invalid: both position 2 and position 9 contain `c`.

To verify that, I wrote this code:

```
valid_case([CAI, CBI, Char, Password]):-
  nth1(CAI, Password, CA),
  nth1(CBI, Password, CB),
  (
    CA == Char,
    CB \== Char
  );(
    CA \== Char,
    CB == Char
  ).
```

However, I get these warnings:

```
Warning: /home/pkoch/github.com/pkoch/aoc-2020/2/2.pl:31:
Warning:    Singleton variable in branch: CA
Warning:    Singleton variable in branch: CB
Warning:    Test is always true: CA\==Char
Warning:    Test is always false: CB==Char
```

Clearly, Prolog is noticing something I'm not. I've tried looking around but everyone points to "you're not using the variable", but I am using them in both branches. Can someone point me in the right direction to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you want to use `=:=` and `=\=` instead of `==` and `\==`. http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/comparison.html

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, == and \== are correct. =:= and =\= are for arithmetic, but we are dealing with characters (atoms of length 1) here.

Comment: pkoch figured out his problem by himself, I guess.

Comment: Yeah. I always mess up the assoc rules and precedence. I was feeling pretty sure of myself, but was still wrong. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

This is what I intended to write:

```
valid_case([CAI, CBI, Char, Password]):-
  nth1(CAI, Password, CA),
  nth1(CBI, Password, CB),
  ((
    CA == Char,
    CB \== Char
  );(
    CA \== Char,
    CB == Char
  )).
```

Comment: This would look cleaner and more idiomatic with the inner pairs of parentheses removed. Out of interest, is there a reason for using a list in the head, i.e., writing `valid_case([CAI, CBI, Char, Password])` instead of `valid_case(CAI, CBI, Char, Password)`?

Comment: API convenience from how I extracted that data from text lines with DCGs.

Comment: Here's the context, to sate curiosities: https://github.com/pkoch/aoc-2020/blob/0dc6ddbc16d2b6da3ff749382bf7475e059c416a/2/2.pl#L31